# Retrieve data from JSON file using PHP routine and feed it to html select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from json file using php and I want this data populated to a html select tag on the front end.

Here is my php file :

```
<?php

ini_set('display-errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$result = file_get_contents('countryBorders.geo.json');

$decode = json_decode($result,true);    

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode;

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);
```

?>

my main js file :

```
 $.ajax({
url: "./php/getBorders.php",
type: 'POST',
dataType: "json",

success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    
    for (let i=0; i< result.data.border.features.length; i++) {
        $('#selCountry').append($('<option>', {
            value: result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a3,
            text: result.data.border.features[i].properties.name,
        }));
       }
    }
});
```

Currently I'm receiving error that method is not allowed. I'm not sure where I'm making mistake here...
If anyone can give me advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why not get the file `countryBorders.geo.json` directly in ajax

Comment: What _"method is not allowed"_? If you have an error message please post the complete text of the message.

Comment: ....and tell us whether the error is coming from PHP or Javascript. Most likely its coming from Javascript - did you try with a sample JSON file and check the output of PHP?

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed is usually what you get when you try to make a POST request, against what the webserver considers to be a "static" resource - i.e., an HTML file, or an image or something like that. Are you sure that `./php/getBorders.php` is the _correct_ path, taking into account what URL you are currently "on" in your browser when this executes ...?

Comment: I'm running the application on VS Code Live Server so the URL path is : http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
and my file path tree is:
css ->> style.css
php -->> getBorders.php
scripts ->> main.js
index.html

Comment: The Error in the browser tell me as per below:
jquery.min.js:2          POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/php/getBorders.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ main.js:24

Comment: That's from debugging console: 

Warning: file_get_contents(./scripts/countryBorders.geo.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\viktorijabagdonaite\Project1\php\getBorders.php on line 9
{"status":{"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"success","returnedIn":"0 ms"},"data":null}

Answer (score 0):

After checking your answers and digging in little more around my code I found that code below done the job feeding json file data to the html select tag
My code snipped below:

```
$('#selCountry').click(function() {
let border;
let name;
$.ajax({
    url: "./php/getBorders.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))

            for (let i=0; i< result.data.border.features.length; i++) {
            $option = $('<option>')
            .val(result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a3)
            .text(result.data.border.features[i].properties.name);
    
                     $('#selCountry').append($option);
            }
            const filterData = result.data.border.features.filter((a) => (a.properties.iso_a3 === name));
            border = L.geoJSON(filterData[0]); 
            myMap.fitBounds(border.getBounds());
          
            
        },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        }); 
    
    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify what was the "*method is not allowed*"? AFAICT your answer is the same as the answer I posted but deleted bcs your comments suggested the problem had nothing to do with your JS.